# Negative spikes in neurons

Tags: neuroscience

I'm new to neuroscience research and came across a term called negative spikes (sometimes also used in conjunction with terms biphasic spikes or positive-negative spikes), but could not find what it meant from scientific papers. Can a spike occur in a negative direction (hyperpolarization from the resting potential first, followed by depolarization) or does this term mean something else entirely?

Comment: Please add context as to where you found the terms. What papers etc.

Comment: this question reminded me of: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2804433/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intracellular recordings of action potentials always show the same format with which you are familiar. There is polarisation which the stimulus reduces, a threshold is reached, there is a positive spike, then repolarisation, hyperpolarisation, a refractory period an a return to the baseline polarisation.

The term "negative spike" applies to extracellular recordings. These measure the potential between a point close to but outside the cell and a reference point. The inflow of cations into the cell causes a drop in extracellular potential, which appears as a negative spike in the recording.